# Is timezone.now().date a function or a callable?

Tags: django, function, callback, django-managers

I'm writing a manager in Django 1.5. I want to return a `QuerySet` that contains objects with a start date either today or in the future. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741772/correct-way-to-use-a-default-date-in-a-django-model) to a previous problem I presume my manager needs to use a callable rather than a function. I've written:

```
...
return super(UpcomingEventManager, self).get_query_set().filter(date__gte=timezone.now().date)
```

I read that code as being a callable (`date`) that relies on a function (`timezone.now()`) for its value. But will Django treat it as a callable or a function?

I know I can test this by creating an object and waiting until tomorrow but I'd rather understand this fully.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be using callback in a way I don't recognise here.

`timezone.now()` returns a value of type `datetime.datetime`. That class has a property, `date`, which returns the date portion of that value. There are no callbacks involved here at all.

**Edit** Your confusion is stemming from a mis-reading of the previous question. That's about default values used in model field declarations: as the answers there state, you need to use a callable rather than a value because the declaration is evaluated on first import.

But that's not what you're doing here at all. You're simply passing a value to a function from another function. There's no early evaluation involved: the code will be evaluated when the function is called, so it's perfectly safe to use `date()` or `today()` there. In fact, in this case passing the callable rather than the value will *not* work.

(Also, you should use the word "callable" rather than "callback" here: a callback implies some sort of asynchronous behaviour, which isn't what's happening.)

Comment: If I understand you correctly then the correct way to do this would be something like `datetime.date.today` then, because that is a callback on the `today` function. Is that right? Also, timezone.now().date returns the date function, not a value.

Comment: I think I understand now. Thanks for this. I've edited the question to clarify terminology as you suggest.

Comment: Chances are that if you use setting `USE_TZ = True` and are using `timezone.now().date()`, what you really want is `timezone.localdate()` otherwise you get the date for the UTC timezone.

Answer (score 13):

Django 1.10 get today date:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 29, 7, 23, 55, 924928, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> timezone.now().date
<built-in method date of datetime.datetime object at 0x7f42512b42a0>
>>> timezone.now().date()
datetime.date(2016, 11, 29)
```